# How to throw WebFaultException with HTTP error codes when using JavascriptCallbackBehavior?

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a .Net server app (holding WCF REST JSONP service) and a javascript application on client side.

To avoid **cross-domain** calls from javascript side we use `JSONP` for communication. To make our life easier with the javascript callbacks from server side we are using `JavascriptCallbackBehavior`: WCF is wrapping all the JSON responses in the callback function.

```
[JavascriptCallbackBehavior(UrlParameterName = "$callback")]
[ServiceBehavior(...)]
public class MySvcREST : ISvcREST
{
   public bool SvcMethod()
   {
      throw new WebFaultException<string>("ERROR!", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
   }
}
```

IF I use the code above I will get the following response from my service:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Fri, 03 Aug 2012 11:43:26 GMT

angular.callbacks._1("ERROR!",500);
```

**EDIT1:** Actually even if I remove the `JavascriptCallbackBehavior` and leave the default `callback` name, I would have similar effect, which is not very good.

I really want to get the **HTTP 500** error code, not a **HTTP 200 OK** with the error inside.

How to solve my problem or is there another way to get JSONP from a WCF service?

Comment: @CarlosFigueira is the master of these things... I'd appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't get any reply to my question, but I found the following, somewhat useful, link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816916.aspx .

I understood that **this behavior is by design**... although from javascript side (jquery / angular js), at this time of writing, there is no way to read the second returned parameter (in my case, the http error code).

So, in the end I am not sure if there is a solution other than a workaround. For now we return a `CustomResult` in which we include a custom error code and message.

It is so disappointing with these web technologies when they don't blend with each other... you are forced to so many workarounds.